# Calendar class in Java, ParseException

Tags: java, calendar, simpledateformat

So, I'm experimenting with the `Calendar` class in Java, and I'm writing a method which returns a Calendar object.

What I want for said method is to return a `Calendar` object containing `"Sun Feb 09 22:49:36 +0000 2014"`.

Now I'm (debatably) not lazy and I have done some work on my method.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
    try {
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse("Sun Feb 09 22:49:36 +0000 2014"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return cal;
```

The problem is it keeps telling me that I got a `ParseException`, that it's an `"Unparseable date"`.

I thought my logic was pretty correct, but I'm starting to doubt it.

I'd prefer it without importing any more than `Calendar`, but `SimpleDateFormat` seems to be pretty handy too.

The less imports the better, I always say.

Anyone see how what I want can be achieved?

**EDIT 1**

Tried to run the code in a main method and just print out the result, with no difference in Exception.

The following is my main:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class TestingMyCalendar {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
    try {
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse("Sun Feb 09 22:49:36 +0000 2014"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(cal);

}
}
```

For those interested, the following is my entire console text after the main crashed:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Feb 09 22:49:36 +0000 2014"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at TestingMyCalendar.main(TestingMyCalendar.java:15)
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1391987659892,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Berlin,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=7,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=10,DAY_OF_YEAR=41,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=14,SECOND=19,MILLISECOND=892,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

Comment: I ran the code and got no exception

Comment: The less imports the better is a very very weird motto to live by in today's world.

Comment: @baba Haha, yeah, odd I guess. Think of it as a temporary motto, which applies only in this method!

Comment: Just tested your code, no exceptions too, ran just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to set your default locale to `Locale.ENGLISH`, otherwise the parser might choke on the `Sun` for Sunday.

Try:

```
   Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Or, specify it as part of the constructor call:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Ah, that Local.ENGLISH was the golden piece of code I needed. Thank you very much for the answer! And you answered first, so you get the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your stacktrace indicates `Europe/Berlin` as the timezone suggests that you are using a German `Locale`. The day or month fields may not match those from your default locale, Try

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
          new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, your answer wast helpful! You have my gratitude!

Comment: I'm actually not German (no idea how my computer managed to make that mistake) but a quick translate, and "Besten Dank" to you!

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct. I'll add a few thoughts.

## Defaults Are Tricky

Probably the most common source of trouble in date-time work is inadvertently relying on:

- Default [time zone](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html)
- Default [locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)

I've come to the conclusion that both should be specified in all my code, as a habit. I don't want my code changing its behavior (or breaking, as in your case) if it happens to be run with a different time zone or locale setting.

The only case where date-time code should use the default is when you truly want to detect and utilize the user's (the JVM's) own settings for localization. And even in this case, I explicitly make a call to retrieve and use the default rather than rely on the implicit default, so as to make my code obvious and self-documenting.

- [DateTimeZone.getDefault()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29)
- [java.util.Locale.getDefault()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault--)

## Joda-Time

As a commenter said, minimizing your imports is indeed a queer goal. Especially with java.util.Calendar and java.util.Date – If ever there were a case for imports it would be those two classes. They are notoriously troublesome, and should be avoided. Use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Or, in Java 8, use the bundled new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), inspired by Joda-Time, defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Note that in Joda-Time, a [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object truly knows its own assigned time zone. That's a big contrast to java.util.Date which has no assigned time zone but its `toString` applies the JVM's default time zone which leads to much confusion.

Here is some example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

```
String input = "Sun Feb 09 22:49:36 +0000 2014";

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy" ).withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH ).withZone( timeZone );
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime( input );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "Same dateTime in UTC/GMT: " + dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC ) );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2014-02-09T17:49:36.000-05:00
Same dateTime in UTC/GMT: 2014-02-09T22:49:36.000Z
```

Comment: Very useful remark about the dangers of using defaults implicitly.

Comment: Woaw. This was very insightful reading. Thank you, for broadening my mind a little further!